# How to apply multiple filters to video(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cifilter

I want to add multiple filters(array of CIFilters) to the AVPlayer.
Is it possible, if it is possible please provide a solution?

The single filter is working fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for your single-filter solution?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Frank Schlegel, but I found the solution itself.
will post the solution soon.